# Passing multiple arguments from IronPython to .NET method

Tags: c#, python, interop, ironpython

I have a class in .NET (C#):

```
public class MyHelper {
    public object exec( string script, params object[] arguments ) {
        // execute script with passed arguments in some external enviroment
    }
}
```

I'm using IronPython runtime in my code to run python scripts, which should in some cases call the "exec" method. I would like serve the comfortable way to call the "exec" method. Something like:

```
helper.exec( "someExternalFunction( {0}, {1}, {3} )", var01, var02, var03 )
```

But I don't know how to declare the "exec" method in C# to achieve this. In python I can use a "*args" argument:

```
def exec( script, *args ):
    ... do something ...
```

I don't want have separate Python method "exec" from "MyHelper" class, because the "MyHelper" class provides complex functionality "in one place".

How should I write the "exec" method declaration in C# to achieve that? Or what other solution should I use?

Thanks

Comment: The way you've declared the exec method should accept multiple arguments. What error are you getting when you attempt to invoke it from IronPython?

Comment: The error is "Error-Code: 16; Message: syntax error".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that "exec" is a keyword in Python so you can't use that as your function name.  You could use "exec_" or execute or something like that instead.  Alternately you could write:

getattr(helper, 'exec')(...)

Comment: You are right. There was primairly problem with the name "exec".
I'm beginner in Python and I didn't know the "exec" is keyword (my fault).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to [this FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/05/13/131493.aspx), the `MyHelper.exec` you've defined should accept both an `array` as the second argument, or any number of `objects` following the first `string`.

If your example call to helper does not invoke as expected, that is probably a limitation of the IronPython interpreter, and probably needs to be [filed as a bug](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/WorkItem/List.aspx). Before filing it as a bug, however, please create a minimal runnable C# script that demonstrates what you're trying to do (show how it works as expected in C#), and an IronPython script that attempts to do the same thing but fails. This will be invaluable toward making the problem work.

In the meantime, why not just call

```
helper.exec( "someExternalFunction( {0}, {1}, {3} )", [var01, var02, var03] )
```

?